# Sending HTTP requests from JavaScript (and handling the reply)

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpwebrequest

I'm fairly new to both HTTP and JS.

I want to display the video (and audio) feed from an IP-based web cam. It has an HTTP based AOP, which accepts requests like

```
http://<ip-address>/cgi/audio/receive.cgi?[&<argument>=<value>]
```

and returns HTTP 200 or HTTP 400, etc

Basically I want to remotely control just about everything about the camera using this sort of interface (volume, zoom, image size, frame per second, etc, etc)

How do I go about sending the HTPP request (when the user clicks a button on the web page) and checking the response?

Can I do it in plain JS? Or do I need to use somethign like JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something that could be done very easily using [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: +1 Thanks. So that is, understandably, asynchronous? I'll try to code it up & see if I can get it working.